# Powershell обрезать до символа

Tags: powershell, split

Добрый день! Подскажите, как обрезать строку до последнего символа `\` ?

У меня есть путь например

```
www.ru/dom/users/login1
```

Мне нужно отсюда получить `login1`,
через `Split` получается отрезать все до первого слеша

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такс, это делается `$peremen.Split("/")[-1]`

Comment: "Такс" - что вы имели в виду? Такси или Такса?